# $A$ has $n$ distinct eigenvalues. Show that $C(A)$ is generated by elements in the form $A^i$ and compute its dimension

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A \in GL(n, \mathbb{R})$. We define the vector space $C(A)=\{B \in GL(n, \mathbb{R}): AB=BA\}.$

Let A have $n$ distinct real eigenvalues. Compute $dim(C(A))$ and show that it is generated by elements in the form $A^i$, where $i \geqslant 0$.

I'm not too good at linear algebra so I don't quite know where to begin. I tried to show that $AB=BA \rightarrow B$ is linear combination of $A^i$ for some $i$, thinking that the rest should come easily enough. However I had no luck.

What is the dimension of $C(A)$ if $A$ is diagonalizable on $\mathbb{R}$ but its eigenvalues are not necessarily dinstinct?

EDIT: Corrected someting. Anyway, this wasn't stated in the question, but I think you have to add the $0$ matrix to $C(A)$ in order to make it a vector subspace.

Comment: That which you are trying to prove is *not* true.

Comment: Try starting with the case in which $A$ is diagonal

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of diagonalisable matrices?

Comment: If you are not good at linear algebra, what are you doing solving a relatively hard linear algebra problem? You should first learn how to walk, then try to run.

Comment: Pardon me, that which I was trying to prove was indeed not true. Perhaps it should be better now? Anyway, yes, I know A is diagonalizable in this case. Now I've got to go but I will think about the case when A is diagonal when I get home.

Comment: Yes, it's better now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out.

First I proceed by showing that $C(A) = L$, where $$L = \{linear\ combinations\ of\ A^i\}$$ for $i \geqslant 0$. Then I show that $dim(L) = n$. I need the following result first:

First step: if $A^i=P^{-1}D^iP$, then $(Id, ... , D^{n-1})$ are a basis of the space of the $(n,n)$ diagonal matrices.
It suffices to show they are linearly independent. But they are, because if we write $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}c_iD^i=0$ we get a Van Der Monde matrix, which has rank $n$ since A has dinstinct eigenvalues, so the only solution is $c_i=0\ \forall\ i$.

Second step: $C(A)=L.\\$

One inclusion is obvious. For the other inclusion, let $B \in C(A)$.
First we note that, if $A$ is diagonal, then $B$ must be diagonal too. This follows easily by comparing the $(i,j)$ element of $AB$ and $BA$.
Then, we note that $A=P^{-1}DP$, where $D$ is diagonal. We have:
$$AB=BA$$
$$P^{-1}DPB=BP^{-1}DP$$
$$D(PBP^{-1})=(PBP^{-1})D$$
which means $PBP^{-1}=D'$ for some diagonal matrix $D'$.
But we can write $$D'=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}c_iD^i=PBP^{-1}$$
$$P^{-1}(\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}c_iD^i)P=B$$
and finally
$$\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}c_iA^i=B$$.

Third step: $(Id, A, ... , A^{n-1})$ is a basis of $C(A)=L$.
It follows easily that they are linearly independent because the $D^i$ are.
Then, for every vector of L, we have

$$\sum\limits_{i=0}^{m}c_iA^i=P^{-1}(\sum\limits_{i=0}^{m}c_iD^i)P=P^{-1}(\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}d_iD^i)P=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}d_iA^i$$

This should conclude the proof. Hope there are no big errors.

As for the second part of the question, I'm not really sure.